# Minecraft Server Executing Scripts

Tags: python, linux, server, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a minecraft world space that can interact with a terminal shell and run commands on the computer directly. I intend to use not just the vanilla server but maybe craftbukkit or spigot.

Is it possible to create a listener on minecraft server.jar and wait for a certain command which executes a script on the computer itself?

Is there a plugin out there made for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new plugin for Bukkit/Spigot (more information [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-plugin-development/)).

In the `onCommand`-Method you can then call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your shell command")` to run commands in the linux shell (can also be used on Windows servers).

See also the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-).